# Query on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Devops and started learning Jenkins. So could you please help me know, whether coding experience of any programming language is required to learn and have practice on Jenkins.

Thanks and Regards,
Srivatsasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be truly effective and master Jenkins, you should learn Groovy. You can run any other types of programs from Jenkins, but any modifying or configuration of Jenkins will be done in Groovy.

That said, you don't have to know groovy at all to use Jenkins. You can do a LOT of what Jenkins can do and never write code. Just configure it in the UI.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you will not need to program anything in order to perform task within Jenkins. You will need knowledge/experience with Maven, Ant, Git, SVN, etc, the particular technology will depend on what you want to do with Jenkins. When I use Jenkins I dont think that I have ever programmed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with Jenkins.

you can program in Jenkins in Groovy,Perl,Python and Bash and you can only perform simple builds ( mvn clean install )

it's all about what you want to do with Jenkins.